Zephirine Drouhin Rose - why are the leaves curling on the new growth?
I planted my Zephirine Drouhin climbing rose about two months ago. The leaves on the new growth are curling. I don’t see any pests. Any help for cause and treatment is appreciated. Thank you.

A photograph or two would help.

I don’t have the answer but have your exact same problem, and all of my other roses are fine. My thought is it’s the rose. I got mine from Home Depot and they were super healthy and are now blooming but plants looks terrible now because of the leaf curl.

@KristaW calcium deficiency or lack of water are two common causes but without pictures it's a shot in the dark.

Leaf curling upward means lack of water/nutrients getting into new leaves. Water is the carrier of nutrients. It can be due to several reason

Salt buildup in soil due to over fertilizing
Lack of watering/dryness in soil
Overwatering, hence root rot, so existing roots are insufficient to carry water and nutrients up to the new leaves
Mineral imbalance in soil, hence roots cannot draw nutrients and water out of the soil efficiently. Usually Ca/Mg deficiency, or perhaps, iron (Fe) deficiency.

You know best what might be causing it, based on your experience with the particular rose plant.
I am having the same issue now with my 2 ZDs. The roses are very healthy and growing, but no flowering buds now, and the new leaves are curling upwards. I tried spraying with fungicide first, to eliminate one cause, now, I am trying to eliminate the other probable causes, one by one (I bought the grafted one from Home Depot, the own root one is from a cutting from a friend)
